# When should we use absolute value by solving this integral?

Tags: integration

I have for example: $\int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{1}{2\eta} d\eta$ with $t_0$ a real constant

and the solution was: $\frac{1}{2}(ln|y|-ln|y_0|)$

But on other case I had: $\int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{1}{\eta} d\eta$

and the solution was: $ln(y)-ln(y_0)$

How can I know when I should use absolute value?

Answer (score 0):

$\ln x$ is defined only for $x>0$.

Do you maybe know at the second case that $y_0>0$ and $y>0$ ?

Comment: No, it only says that $y_0$ is real

Comment: In both cases it says only that $y_0$ is real? @JellyBelly

Comment: yes, could the solution be wrong?